# Don't get full Json of the Twitter Api (C#, application-only auth)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, twitter

I don't get the full Json when I make a request to the Twitter API with C#. I use the following code:

```
public static async Task<string> GetTwitterList(string bearerToken)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/show.json?slug=odyssee&owner_screen_name=dieVanDeIlias");

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", bearerToken));
        request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;

        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        Stream reponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        Encoding encoder = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(reponseStream, encoder);
        Char[] read = new Char[256];

        int count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);

        String str = "000";

        while (count > 0)
        {
            str = new String(read, 0, count);
            count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
        }

        readStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return str;
    }
```

I'm using application only authorization. It's for a Asp.Net Web Pages application, so not every http/web class is available. Except when it isn't possible to do this without third-party libraries, I don't want to use them... I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web with .Net version 4.5.

Comment: Do you at least get part of the json? Have you tried the StreamReader.ReadToEnd method?

Comment: I hope you want to do very minimal stuff with the Twitter API because it could take you a while to get all the information you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StreamReader.ReadToEnd method works for me! My code now:

```
public static async Task<string> GetTwitterList(string bearerToken)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json?slug=odyssee&owner_screen_name=dieVanDeIlias");

        string result = "";

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", bearerToken));
        request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;

        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        Encoding encoder = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

        string contentLength = response.Headers.Get("Content-Length");
        int contentLengthInt = Convert.ToInt32(contentLength);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoder))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What's about common functions ?  https://twittercommunity.com/t/samples-in-c-net/25803